# perform href before onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I've the following link:

```
<a href="#HDR" onClick="showGallery()">I</a>
```

And this use the following javascript:

```
function showGallery(){
    if(window.location.hash) {
      $('#gallery').fadeIn('fast');
      var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      alert(hash);
    } else {

    }

}
```

So it only show the gallery when in the URL is a hashtag. But when i click on the link, nothing happens. When i click it twice, the gallery fade in.

So the link first make the javascript, and i doesn't work 'cause there is no hashtag in the URL and after that, it perform the href and insert the Hashtag in the URL. 
How can i do that?

My Target:

When i click on a link, it open a gallery. To know which gallery i must open, i insert in the URL a Hashtag. Here i want to display the HDR album. And i also want, if my site get opend with a hashtag, it should display the gallery.!

Is there also a another, easier or cleaner way to make it?
Hope you understand what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For modern browsers, you can bind your Javascript code to the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event. Links will be without Javascript:

```
<a href="#HDR">I</a>
```

And the Javascript is run whenever the hash has changed:

```
function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#HDR") {
        $('#gallery').fadeIn('fast');
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Comment: Nice! Thats the "elegant" method :) Thank you +1 and accept ;) But what does window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged; mean?

Comment: It adds an event handler, so that the function `locationHashChanged` is called whenever the `hashchange` event is triggered on the window. In jQuery this would be `$(window).bind('hashchange', locationHashChanged)`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a setTimeout call to delay the onclick event?

Like this:

```
<a href="#HDR" onClick="setTimeout(function(){showGallery.call(this)},20)">I</a>
```

Comment: Damn ugly.. but in my situation it's the only possible way. Dah!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this quite considerably, it is not good practice to use the href for other things than pure navigation.

```
<a onClick="showGallery('HDR')">I</a>
```

And then:

```
function showGallery(name){
    if(name) {
        $('#gallery').fadeIn('fast');
        alert(name);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: i also tried this. But then the gallery only opend with this link. i also want to show it if #HDR in the url and i update the site. e.g with CTRL + R

Comment: Ahh ok, then you should go with Sjoerd's answer below but you may want to do a bit more reading around the hash changed stuff and which browsers are supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run showGallery() without following the link, the correct code is this:

```
<a href="#HDR" onClick="showGallery(); return false;">I</a>
```

By keeping the `href` the user still sees the destination in the status bar and navigation still works for clients without Javascript (i.e. Google). By returning false in the event handler, you prevent the browser from following the link.

In showGallery(), you can then show the gallery and add '#HDR' to the location.hash.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to verify the window's hash, because on first click you don't have any hash in the address bar. The functionality will only apply on the second click.

What you can do is this:

`<a href="#HDR" id="g1" onClick="showGallery('g1')">gallery 1</a>`

```
function showGallery(galid){
    var linkhash = $('#' + galid).attr('href').substring(1);

    alert(linkhash);

    $('#gallery' + linkhash).fadeIn('fast');
}
```