# Trigger an href event only before the onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found so many articles about "Trigger an href event only after the onclick" but my requirement is almost opposite i.e. "Trigger an href event only before the onclick".
I want my href execute first and then my onclick event.

Here is my code:

```
<li id="menu-users" class="dropdown">
    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Manage Users<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="manage_a" onclick="keepNavMenuOpen()">Manage A</a></li>
        <li><a href="manage_b" onclick="keepNavMenuOpen()">Manage B</a></li>
        <li><a href="manage_c" onclick="keepNavMenuOpen()">Manage C</a></li>
        <li><a href="manage_d" onclick="keepNavMenuOpen()">Manage D</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>


function keepNavMenuOpen() {
    var element = document.getElementById("menu-users");
    element.classList.add("open");
}
```

Comment: [Old Answer, but should still work according to docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743925/perform-href-before-onclick)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [perform href before onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743925/perform-href-before-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a setTimeout call to delay the onclick event?

Like this:

```
<li><a href="manage_a" onClick="setTimeout(function(){keepNavMenuOpen.call(this)},20)">Manage A</a></li>
```

Refer to here: 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743925/perform-href-before-onclick/13743968#13743968)

Comment: Would be better to point to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743968/489884) instead of copying it here.

Answer (score -1):

You are misusing the anchor element in place of the button element. Change to `<button>` elements then attach your behaviors to it.

Source: [MDN's  Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

> Anchor tags are often abused with the onclick event to create
>   pseudo-buttons by setting href to "#" or "javascript:void(0)" to
>   prevent the page from refreshing. These values cause unexpected
>   behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new
>   tabs/windows, bookmarking, and when JavaScript is still downloading,
>   errors out, or is disabled. This also conveys incorrect semantics to
>   assistive technologies (e.g., screen readers). In these cases, it is
>   recommended to use a  instead. In general you should only use
>   an anchor for navigation using a proper URL.

Comment: OP does appear to have a URL set to href though.

Comment: I cant use buttons that's my limitation. and adding onclick="keepNavMenuOpen() to <li> doesn't work as well

Comment: then just use a `<span>` (or the raw `li`) along with CSS `:hover{cursor:pointer;}` and style t to make it behave like a button or anchor.